# What's the right way to schedule multiple future payments without consistent intervals with Stripe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I am trying to achieve the following: set up future payments that don’t have a consistent interval (for example, a payment now and a payment on 2 more pre-set dates). I have an object of dates and amounts and I am creating a subscription for each that I cancel before a second charge is made.

```js
const _payments = stripePayments.map(async (payment) => {
  try {
    const price = await stripe.prices.create({
      unit_amount: payment.amount * 100,
      currency: 'usd',
      recurring: { interval: 'year' },
      product: process.env.SCRIPE_PRODUCT
    })

    const subscription = {
      customer: customerId,
      items: [{ price: price.id }],
      billing_cycle_anchor: payment.dueDate,
      cancel_at: addYears(new Date(payment.dueDate), 1)
    }

    return await stripe.subscriptions.create(subscription)
  }

  catch (error) {
    throw new Error('creating Stripe subscription failed ' + error)
  }
})
```

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a better way to do it?
2. In the billing I see a small charge made right after the subscription. Why is that? Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Can you add additional context regarding the small charge that you're referring to so the community can better understand the behavior that you're concerned with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriptions aren't a good fit if you're dealing with inconsistent billing intervals, as Subscriptions are designed to automatically process payments on a recurring basis based on consistent billing intervals. Leveraging Subscriptions will also result in there being more objects that you need to maintain and clean up.

The code you shared will do more than process a payment in the future. When setting `billing_cycle_anchor` during the creation of a Subscription, the resulting Subscription will immediately process a prorated payment for the portion of the Subscription before the `billing_cycle_anchor` date and then process another full-price payment on the `billing_cycle_anchor` date. ([source](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#new-subscriptions))

Stripe has a process that allows you to collect a payment method, then use that payment method to make a payment at a point in the future. You can view the full guide on that [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse).

The drawback with the above approach, is that it requires you or your system to make the request to create/process the Payment Intent when you want to process a payment in the future. If you need a way to schedule these payments to occur in the future, then Subscription Schedules are the best option as they allow you to schedule the creation of Subscriptions. However, Subscription Schedules can be a bit tedious to work with, and still result in Subscription objects that you need to maintain and clean up to ensure they don't generate any unexpected payments. I would recommend using the process linked above instead of Subscription Schedules for these reasons, but below are some useful resources if you decide to work with Subscription Schedules.

- https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#start-subscription-future
- https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules

Additional context is needed regarding your second question to understand what charge you're referring to.

Comment: OK thank you. The charges I am referring to are the ones highlighted in red in the picture. Also, I will probably go with the future payments, but out of curiosity: what parameter should I use in the subscription object to avoid those initial payments?

Comment: The best approach to avoid a Subscription immediately processing a payment when it is created, is to create it with a trial period. You can use the `trial_end` parameter during Subscription creation to specify when the trial period for a Subscription should end and the first payment should be processed. Thanks for adding the screenshot, but it doesn't tell us much beyond the fact there were payments triggered by Subscriptions for that Customer. That might be the first prorated payment that I mentioned earlier.